# Scraping data between two spans scrapy

Tags: python, css, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm scraping a web and want to get the price information of all products on the first page. Below is the html of the web. I want to get 99.

```
<div class = 'item-bg'>
    <div class = 'product-box'>
        <div class = 'res-info'>
            <div class = 'price-box'>
                <span class = 'def-price selectorgadget_rejected'>
                    <i>$</i>
                    99
                    <i>.99</i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't think I can use the def-price class because some products have 'selectorgadget_rejected' and some products have 'selectorgadget_suggested' after it.
My code right now is

```
product_info = response.css('.item-bg')
for product in product_info:
    product_price_sn = product.css('.price-box').extract()
```

It's not getting 99 and I'm not sure how to fix it. Any ideas?

Here is the screenshot of the full HTML info:
[image: suning html]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always prefer to use XPath over CSS. In XPath you could use the `contains` function to specify which classes you want to select, like:

```
response.xpath('//span[contains(@class, "def-price selectorgadget")]//text()').extract()
```

- This would extract text from **ALL** the `<span>` tags in the page which it's class contained the expression `def-price selectorgadget` wheter it be `selectorgadget_rejected` or `selectorgadget_suggested`.

Or using the pre-selected `product_info`:

```
product_info = response.css('.item-bg')
for product in product_info:
    product_price_sn = product.xpath('div/div/div/span[contains(@class, "def-price selectorgadget")]//text()').extract()
```

*Using full path because only snippet of HTML was posted*

If you want only the 99 **outside** the `<i>` tags use `/text()` instead of `//text()`

---

### CSS Selector

Now, in case you want to stick with the CSS selectors, this **might** work:

```
product.css('.price-box span::text').extract()
```

Comment: I used the code `product_price_sn = product.xpath('div/div/div/span[contains(@class, "def-price selectorgadget")]//text()').extract()` but it's not getting anything?  When I run the spider, it prints [] in terminal. I'm not sure if it's because only snippet of html was provided earlier? I uploaded a screenshot of the full html.

Comment: Hi @TianheXie First, can you make sure you get an return with this `response.xpath('//span[contains(@class, "def-price selectorgadget")]//text()').extract() `? If you do, can you also try  `product.xpath('//span[contains(@class, "def-price selectorgadget")]//text()').extract()`?

Comment: I'd also recommend using get() method instead of extract_first() and getall() instead of extract. Just another little tip.